# PHP: trying to read data from Serial COM port ( Windows )

Tags: php, serial-port

I am tired of working with Serial comport to send and receive data ( Windows ). I have tried every possible way. Every time i got able to connect and send data. But when it comes to receiving lines script got hanged.

I am sure device which is connected to comport is working as it returned data when reading through windows power shell.

There are two most common methods i have tried are:

1 [PhpSerial.php](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial)  ( Line: 597 )

2 Direct-Dio library

By using Direct-Dio
getting Hanged on > $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort, 1024);

```
<?php


$portName = 'com1:';
$baudRate =9600;
$bits = 8;
$spotBit = 1;

header( 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' ); 
?>
Serial Port Test
================
<?php


function echoFlush($string)
{
echo $string . "\n";
flush();
ob_flush();
}

if(!extension_loaded('dio'))
{
echoFlush( "PHP Direct IO does not appear to be installed for more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php" );
exit;
}

try 
{
$output = exec('$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one',$results);
exec( '
    ' );
exec( '$port.WriteLine("<A>")',$results );
$test = exec( '$port.ReadLine()',$results );
echo $test;

print_r($results);

//the serial port resource
$bbSerialPort;

echoFlush(  "Connecting to serial port: {$portName}" );

if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') 
{ 
    $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR );
    //we're on windows configure com port from command line
    exec("mode {$portName} baud={$baudRate} data={$bits} stop={$spotBit} parity=n xon=on");

} 
else //'nix
{
    $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );
    dio_fcntl($bbSerialPort, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);
    //we're on 'nix configure com from php direct io function
    dio_tcsetattr($bbSerialPort, array(
        'baud' => $baudRate,
        'bits' => $bits,
        'stop'  => $spotBit,
        'parity' => 0
    ));
}

if(!$bbSerialPort)
{
    echoFlush( "Could not open Serial port {$portName} ");
    exit;
}


// send data

$dataToSend = "<A>";
echoFlush( "Writing to serial port data: \"{$dataToSend}\"" );
$bytesSent = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToSend );
echoFlush( "Sent: {$bytesSent} bytes" );
exec("mode {$portName} baud={$baudRate} data={$bits} stop={$spotBit} parity=n xon=on");
//date_default_timezone_set ("Europe/London");

$runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT3S"); //10 seconds
$endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);

echoFlush(  "Waiting for {$runForSeconds->format('%S')} seconds to recieve data on serial port" );
dio_seek($bbSerialPort, -8, SEEK_END);


while (new DateTime() < $endTime) 
{
$data ="";
    $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort, 1024); //this is a blocking call
    if ($data) {
        echoFlush(  "Data Received: ". $data );
    }
}
$output = exec ( '$port.ReadLine()',$results );
print_r($results);
 exec ( '$port.Close()' );
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";  echoFlush(  "Closing Port" );       dio_close($bbSerialPort);   
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
echoFlush('CATCH');
echoFlush(  $e->getMessage() );
exit(1);
} 

?>
```

I din't find any solution on internet.

Comment: What errors are in the log file?

Comment: there was no error .. just like dio_read and fread are waiting for data... and i have connected a weighting machine which is returning weight from Windows power shell

Comment: somebody please look at it thoroughly it will solve problem

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are sending data from the device? Can you talk to it with other terminal programs?