# PHP serial com port sent and receive data

Tags: php, serial-port

I am working to connect a Serial COM port to send and receive data through PHP.
And I don't have device so i have created a [Virtual com port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port) to test data.

I can see my code is sending data as i can see the sent bytes on VSPD interface.
But problem is that i can't receive data for testing purpose i want to read as well.

Is there any good Virtual com port emulator or any other suggestion ?

```
exec("mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off");
$fp = fopen("com3", "w");
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Not open";
} else {
    sleep(10);
    echo "Open";
    fwrite($fp, "jhh0");
    $buff = fread($fp, 10);
    echo ">> ".$buff." <<";
    //fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: You're opening the port in `w` mode (write-only). Try opening it in `w+` (read/write) mode.

Comment: ok then how should i receive data.. i want to display anything even OK message works for me. i just want to test code

Comment: If you open in read/write mode, your `fread()` call should work for receiving response data.

Comment: Actually i was working on actual device... it hangs while reading so i want to read and display as well..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439255/php-trying-to-read-data-from-serial-com-port-windows  this is also our post ....

Comment: https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial/blob/develop/src/PhpSerial.php check out line 597 fread was not working there

Comment: Heh, I was just about to post a link to a [simplified version](https://github.com/lepiaf/serialport) of that library. You might want to look into using that, or seeing how they communicate with a serial port.